# Server not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How and where do I add the message "Server not available" if I have a code that calls a php file from a remote server but the php file is unavailable? Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="Javascript"> 
        function View(){
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://someremoteserver/somephpfile.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="View();" >
    <div id="datatable" align="center"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Why do you tag "jquery" when you don't use jquery?
In jQuery you could do a cross domain request with jsonp datatype.
The callback "failure" has 3 params. With one you can get the http status (503 for Service Unavailable).

Answer (score 3):

You could detect the different [HTTP Status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and do something based on the response. Or you could just implement a generic handler if the status isn't 200:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
    } else if (xmlhttp.status == 503) { //specific error code
        alert('Sorry, this server is unavailable');
    } else { //generic error handler
        alert('There was an error with your request');
    }
}
```

Comment: cfs this works fine but instead of alert how do I display the message on the page? is it document.write?

Comment: @user2430338 Great glad I could help :) And welcome to StackOverflow! It's encouraged here to accept and upvote an answer if it helped you solve your problem, that way other people who have the same question will be able to find the answer. Thanks and good luck!